# Can't wake up from sleep

Tags: nvidia, suspend, horus, nvidia-driver

As i said in the title, i can't wake my laptop from sleep.
All i after waking up the pc is a black screen with "_" not even blinking, but just static.
When i try to press "CTRL + ALT + F1" the login screen appears in tty1, but the pc is stuck, and i can't even get again in the graphic session by pressing "CTRL + ALT + F7".
The only solution i have is to shutdown the pc and boot again, loosing all the work i was doing.
I'm using nvidia 535 drivers, i've also tried the 525, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use open source drivers `nouveau` and don't use NVIDIA proprietary drivers if you want the sleep option. If you want to keep both, you can look up for how to do it as I have seen people configuring `systemd` a lot just to achieve both.